# Nuxt.js + BootstrapVue: How to place the form card in the center of the page?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a card with form/ I want to place in the center of the page.

Here my layout 'empty':

```
<template>
    <nuxt />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Empty'
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

I have next page with form:

```
<template>
  <b-card>
    <b-form @submit.stop.prevent="onSubmit">
      ...
    </b-form>
  </b-card>
</template>
```

I get next result:

```
<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true">
    <div id="__nuxt">
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <div id="__layout">
            <div class="card">
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!---->
                    <!---->
                    <form class="">
                    ...
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!---->
                <!---->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

On the screen, it looks like:
[image]

But I want to it looks like:
[image]

I can't find how to do it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of bootstrap v4.3 [flex utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/) and [position utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/position/) with a sprinkling of custom styling:

```html
<div
  class="fixed-top d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
  style="bottom: 0; overflow-y: auto"
>
  <b-card style="max-width: 400px;">
    <form>
      <b-form-input class="mb-2"></b-form-input>
      <b-form-input class="mb-2"></b-form-input>
      <b-form-input class="mb-2"></b-form-input>
      <b-form-input class="mb-2"></b-form-input>
    </form>
  </b-card>
</div>
```

You may need to tweak the above styles a bit.